# Get script's url by handle (in wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, enqueue

Is it possible to get a script url from one of my working scripts, by handle?

So for example if i have a plugin's JS file registered with the handle wp-js-plugin and i want to get this JS file's url. how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more info dump `$wp_scripts`

```
function get_script_src_by_handle($handle) {
    global $wp_scripts;
    if(in_array($handle, $wp_scripts->queue)) {
        return $wp_scripts->registered[$handle]->src;
    }
}
```

Comment: great! Thanks! is there a way to return the script if it is registered or not...? (will '$wp_scripts->[$handle]->src' work?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: Let's say this script is deregistered and i want to get is url. is it possible?

Comment: I do not think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple:

`const scriptUrls = [...document.querySelectorAll('script')].map(e=>e.src)`

This will list all the urls for each script.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear in my question. i'm looking for a way of echoing a specific script url. ("i will give you the scripts handle and you will echo the script's url)